# chromium-browser - can't launch site from command line

Tags: command-line, raspberry-pi, chrome

I have a static html site at `localhost`.  When I open Chromium and manually enter `localhost` into the address bar, the site appears and behaves correctly.

However, when I type the following from the terminal...

```
chromium-browser localhost
```

...Chromium opens, `localhost` appears in the address bar, but the page never loads and I end up with "Do you want to wait."

I'm running Raspberry Pi

**lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

**cat /proc/version**

```
Linux version 5.15.32-v8+ (dom@buildbot) (aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1538 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 31 19:40:39 BST 2022
```

How do I launch the page from command line?

ETA:
I tried the following URLs after `chromium-browser`

- localhost (as described above)
- http://localhost
- [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
- https://www.google.com

Each had the same result.

In the terminal window the following error messages appear (I'm exercising my google-fu to see if these messages guide me to a solution):

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[6181:6181:0420/125426.351921:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is egl, ANGLE is
[6181:6181:0420/125426.457777:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[6312:6312:0420/125429.016432:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is egl, ANGLE is
[6312:6312:0420/125429.154421:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[6358:6358:0420/125429.257975:ERROR:egl_util.cc(74)] Failed to load GLES library: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libGLESv2.so: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[6358:6358:0420/125429.298887:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[6367:6367:0420/125429.388139:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
[6129:6186:0420/125436.969258:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[6129:6186:0420/125436.969526:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=330711#p1990605

I blindly tried its suggestion, which was to execute the following:

```
echo 'export CHROMIUM_FLAGS="$CHROMIUM_FLAGS --use-gl=egl"' | sudo tee /etc/chromium.d/egl
```

(that is, it creates a file `/etc/chromium.d/egl` which contains the command to set that envar).

It worked.  Someday I may even try to understand why.